# Cannot run X in Archlinux installed in VMPlayer

Tags: xorg, arch-linux, vmware-player

I have installed archlinux in VMPlayer (host OS is windows). But I cannot get X run after install all the packages and drivers according to manual.
All I get is `vmware(0): Failed to detect device screen object capability.` and segmentation  fault at 0x8.

I cannot find any info about the error online. What is causing this error and how might I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is caused by the `xf86-video-vmware` package.

Remove the package and install a more generic video driver, such as `xf86-video-fbdev` or the default `xf86-video-vesa`.

You may lose some functionality by doing this, but at least you'll get your system running (hopefully).

An alternative would be to try to downgrade the above package until you find an earlier version that works - details on the [Arch Forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=185006).

Comment: Thank you! Problem solved after I change to xf86-video-fbdev and add `needs_root_rights = yes` to `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config`